# Get Files in One Drive Folder Sorted By Updated Time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, onedrive

I have an apps that allow user to pick an apps backups from specific folder in `One Drive`.

I want to show only 10 files from this folder sorted by file `Updated Time` (DESC), I have found how to limit the files by appending `limit=10` to query path.

I'm using **Live SDK ver 5.6.1** package from `Nuget`.

```
LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
var result = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/files?limit=10", folderId));
```

But cannot find how to sorted by `Updated Time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure we are using the same version of the REST API, but the one documented at http://onedrive.github.io/index.htm (using dollar notation for the parameters) uses *$orderby* . For example,

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/[FOLDER ID]/children?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime%20desc
```

However, if you are stuck on the older Live SDK, according to the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx you should be able to use

```
FOLDER_ID/files?sort_by=updated&sort_order=descending
```

That's exactly what Clint suggested, so if that doesn't work for you, you might want to consider updating to the newer API. I can confirm that sorting definitely works there.

Comment: I'm using `Live SDK` package from `Nuget`, my apps throws exception after I modified my query to use `[FOLDER ID]/children?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime%20desc`.
Errors: `The URL contains the path 'children', which isn't supported`.

Comment: The OneDrive API is the successor of the Live SDK, so we are indeed on different API's here.

Comment: Updated my answer with the different API calls

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but...

```
var result = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/files?limit=10&sort_by=updated", folderId));
```

Comment: I try it, but have no effect on returned files.