# How to get files from onedrive in c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a requirement that is we need to access onedirve through asp.net/C# and need to         get the latest uploaded file..? 
Please help me how to solve this type of requirement..? 
i tried the following code..

i used following namespaces. but didn't work

```
 using Microsoft.Live.Web.Samples.ConnectAppUserWithMSAccount.Filters;
 using Microsoft.Live.Web.Samples.ConnectAppUserWithMSAccount.Models;



private LiveAuthClient MSAuthClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.liveAuthClient == null)
            {
                IDictionary<int, string> secretMap = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                secretMap.Add(ClientSecretKey, ClientSecret);
                this.liveAuthClient = new LiveAuthClient(ClientId, secretMap, null, this);
            }

            return this.liveAuthClient;
        }
    }

 private MSAccountStatus MSAccountStatus
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.msAccountStatus == Controllers.MSAccountStatus.None)
            {
                using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                {
                    MSAccount msAccount = db.MSAccounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name);
                    this.msAccountStatus = msAccount != null ? MSAccountStatus.Connected : MSAccountStatus.NotConnected;
                }
            }

            if (this.msAccountStatus == MSAccountStatus.Connected)
            {
                LiveConnectSession session = this.MSAuthClient.Session;
                if (session == null || session.Expires < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                {
                    this.msAccountStatus = MSAccountStatus.ConnectedWithError;
                }
            }

            return this.msAccountStatus;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You provided some code, but it appears to be unrelated. Where is your attempt at retrieving the file?

Comment: It looks like you are using the LiveSDK for Windows, that API/SDK pair is deprecated, I would recommend you take a look at the work being done here: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp

Comment: @PeterNied i saw the code but it will not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485895/get-files-in-one-drive-folder-sorted-by-updated-time